# FTP: Why have linefeeds been converted to carriage returns?

Tags: ftp

I'm running a RHEL machine that was, by default, running vsftpd, the very secure ftp daemon. Due to its lack of configuration and symlink support, I've switched to pure-ftpd.

I noticed that files that used to have linefeeds `\n` now instead have two carriage returns `\r`.

I've tried switching back in forth between the servers, and the file is untouched, but it seems that the FTP server is doing something different. Using `vi`/`vim` as well as `cat` show a single linefeed, but the downloaded file from pure-ftpd shows two carriage returns. Note that this applied only to certain files, many files transfer normally, including all system-created files.

What causes this to happen? If this isn't a setting, how would I fix the files without opening them one by one and replacing `\r\r` with `\n`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to tell your client to transfer in binary mode.

Comment: One question - why would this change between FTP server types if this is a client-side option?

Comment: It's a negotiated option.  I believe the default is set by the server, but I'm not sure of that.